# Class X with object of class Y, access public variables of X from within Y

Tags: c++, singleton, global

Given a custom class `X` with a vector of instances of another custom class `Y`, **I would like to access the public variables of class `X` from within an instance of `Y`** using e.g. a global reference or pointer to the instance of `X`. Ultimately, class `Z` contains the instance of class `X` (right now, there can only be one instance of `X` at a time, which hints at the use of a singleton).

Naturally, this is a simplified (and somewhat abstract) version of the actual problem, which contains more classes with certain dependencies (including circular ones). Now, before someone starts with "... don't use global variables or pointers, don't use circular dependencies, ..." — I know, please just assume I have a good reason for using them in this case. In general I too like to avoid them.

The initial idea was to make `myX` (defined in class `Z`) globally available, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this properly. If I were to use `myX` from within `Y` (e.g. using `extern`), `Y` would have to know about class `X`. But I can't include the header of `X` here. I could use a forward declaration of `X`, but then `Y` still wouldn't know about `myObjectsY`. Clearly, this doesn't work.

---

Class X

```
#include 'Y.h'    

class X {
  public:      
  vector<Y> myObjectsY;
};
```

Class Y

```
class Y {
  // How to obtain e.g. the number of objects Y in the myObjectsY vector
};
```

Class Z

```
#include 'X.h'

class Z {
  X *myX = new X();
};
```

Comment: I don't really get what the problem with forward declaring X is, can you clarifiy?

Comment: @Knoep I thought about that, but then all instances of `Y` would contain the same pointer to `X`. So as I see it, the same information would be stored a considerable number of times (or would the compiler be smart here somehow)?

Comment: Pointers are very small, you should worry about that. Also, you NEED this information in every single instance of Y.

Comment: @Knoep My previous comment is a reaction to your first comment that now disappeared. There is no problem with forward declaring `X`, but in that case, `Y` is only aware of the class `X`, but does not know anything about the methods/variables/... of `X`, right? That *is* an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply forward declare X in Y.h and give Y a pointer to X. If you include X.h in Y.cpp you can than access members of X in functions that are defined in Y.cpp (as the definition of X is known at that point).

Comment: Ok, added a forward declaration to `X` as well as a pointer to `X`, say `X *pX`. Now, using e.g. `pX->myObjectsY.size()` in `Y` results in an error that, in the example setting, would be `invalid use of incomplete type 'class X'`. What am I missing?

Comment: Try putting the defintion of the function that accesses X in the cpp file. And give me a minute to figure out why this could matter...

Comment: ... and include x.h in that cpp file.

Comment: But including `x.h` also results in the inclusion of `y.h`, right?

Comment: Yeah, but that should be included in y.cpp anyway. Sorry for the confusion, took me a bit to sort out my knowledge of forward declaration. I'll set the answer strait.

Comment: And for the record: You were totally right that you cannot access members of forward declared classes. This just doesn't usually matter, because if you use this setup (which is quite typical) they are no longer just forward declared by the point you try to access the members (in the .cpp file).

Comment: Ok, I see how this works. Thanks. However, in the actual problem, the equivalent of `x.h` is a header with quite a lot of other `#include` statements, methods and variables. In addition, it will not only be included in the equivalent of `y.cpp`, but also in four other classes with similar characteristics as `Y` (but not enough to create a template for them). Would a global pointer not be a better approach in that case?

Comment: It will not be included in y.h, only in y.cpp. I don't see why this would be a problem? If you don't use all those definitions and declarations in y.cpp, the compile won't include them in the bytecode for the compilation unit.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say `y.cpp` instead of `y.h`, fixed. Well, the approach should still work, but including `x.h` now also includes a lot of other stuff, and again that does not seem completely efficient. Maybe the compiler will be smart, I don't know. Just wondering if there is a more elegant solution :).

Comment: See the edit of my last comment. In C++ you don't pay for what you don't use :) And this approach is really quite typical, I doubt there is a better solution.

Comment: The only alternatives I can think of are a global construction using `extern`, or something involving a singleton. I'm not saying those would be more elegant though. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one if no others are provided on short term. Cheers!

Comment: Fine, I can wait :)